# terraform keeps forcing new resource/force replacement for container definition with default parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am bringing up `aws_ecs_task_defintion` with following terraform configuration.

I pass `local.image_tag` as variable to control the deployment of our ecr image through terraform.

I am able to bring up the ecs_cluster on initial terraform plan/apply cycle just fine.

However, on the subsequent terraform plan/apply cycle, terraform is forcing the new container definition and thats why redeploying the entire task definition even though our ecr image `local.image_tag` remains just same

This behaviour, is causing the unintended task definition recycle without any changes to the ecr image and just terraform forcing values with defaults.

**TF Config**

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "this_task" {
  family                   = "this-service"
  execution_role_arn       = var.this_role
  task_role_arn            = var.this_role
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = 256
  memory                   = var.env != "prod" ? 512 : 1024
  tags                     = local.common_tags
  # Log the to datadog if it's running in the prod account.
  container_definitions = (
    <<TASK_DEFINITION
[
    {
        "essential": true,
        "image": "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/thisisservice:${local.image_tag}",
        "environment" :[
            {"name":"ID", "value":"${jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.this_decrypt.secret_string)["id"]}"},
            {"name":"SECRET","value":"${jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.this_decrypt.secret_string)["secret"]}"},
            {"name":"THIS_SOCKET_URL","value":"${local.websocket_url}"},
            {"name":"THIS_PLATFORM_API","value":"${local.platform_api}"},
            {"name":"REDISURL","value":"${var.redis_url}"},
            {"name":"BASE_S3","value":"${aws_s3_bucket.ec2_vp.id}"}
        ],
        "name": "ec2-vp",
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
            "options": {
                "Name": "datadog",
                "apikey": "${jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.datadog_api_key[0].secret_string)["api_key"]}",
                "Host": "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com",
                "dd_service": "this",
                "dd_source": "this",
                "dd_message_key": "log",
                "dd_tags": "cluster:${var.cluster_id},Env:${var.env}",
                "TLS": "on",
                "provider": "ecs"
            }
        },
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 443,
                "hostPort": 443
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "essential": true,
        "image": "amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest",
        "name": "log_router",
        "firelensConfiguration": {
            "type": "fluentbit",
            "options": { "enable-ecs-log-metadata": "true" }
        }
    
    }
]
TASK_DEFINITION
)
}
```

```
-/+ resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "this_task" {
              ~ arn                      = "arn:aws:ecs:ca-central-1:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/this:4" -> (known after apply)
              ~ container_definitions    = jsonencode(
                  ~ [ # forces replacement
                      ~ {
                          - cpu              = 0 -> null
                            environment      = [
                                {
                                    name  = "BASE_S3"
                                    value = "thisisthevalue"
                                },
                                {
                                    name  = "THIS_PLATFORM_API"
                                    value = "thisisthevlaue"
                                },
                                {
                                    name  = "SECRET"
                                    value = "thisisthesecret"
                                },
                                {
                                    name  = "ID"
                                    value = "thisistheid"
                                },
                                {
                                    name  = "THIS_SOCKET_URL"
                                    value = "thisisthevalue"
                                },
                                {
                                    name  = "REDISURL"
                                    value = "thisisthevalue"
                                },
                            ]
                            essential        = true
                            image            = "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/this:v1.0.0-develop.6"
                            logConfiguration = {
                                logDriver = "awsfirelens"
                                options   = {
                                    Host           = "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com"
                                    Name           = "datadog"
                                    TLS            = "on"
                                    apikey         = "thisisthekey"
                                    dd_message_key = "log"
                                    dd_service     = "this"
                                    dd_source      = "this"
                                    dd_tags        = "thisisthetags"
                                    provider       = "ecs"
                                }
                            }
                          - mountPoints      = [] -> null
                            name             = "ec2-vp"
                          ~ portMappings     = [
                              ~ {
                                    containerPort = 443
                                    hostPort      = 443
                                  - protocol      = "tcp" -> null
                                },
                            ]
                          - volumesFrom      = [] -> null
                        } # forces replacement,
                      ~ {
                          - cpu                   = 0 -> null
                          - environment           = [] -> null
                            essential             = true
                            firelensConfiguration = {
                                options = {
                                    enable-ecs-log-metadata = "true"
                                }
                                type    = "fluentbit"
                            }
                            image                 = "amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest"
                          - mountPoints           = [] -> null
                            name                  = "log_router"
                          - portMappings          = [] -> null
                          - user                  = "0" -> null
                          - volumesFrom           = [] -> null
                        } # forces replacement,
                    ]
                )
                cpu                      = "256"
                execution_role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNTID:role/thisistherole"
                family                   = "this"
              ~ id                       = "this-service" -> (known after apply)
                memory                   = "512"
                network_mode             = "awsvpc"
                requires_compatibilities = [
                    "FARGATE",
                ]
              ~ revision                 = 4 -> (known after apply)
                tags                     = {
                    "Cluster"      = "this"
                    "Env"          = "this"
                    "Name"         = "this"
                    "Owner"        = "this"
                    "Proj"         = "this"
                    "SuperCluster" = "this"
                    "Terraform"    = "true"
                }
                task_role_arn            = "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT+ID:role/thisistherole"
            }
```

Above is the terraform plan that is forcing new task definition/container definition.

As you can see , terraform is replacing all default values with null or empty. I have double check the terraform.tfstate file it already generated from the previous run and those values are exactly the same as its showing on the above plan.

I am not sure why this unintended behaviour is happening and want to have some clues on how to fix this.

I am using terraform 0.12.25 and latest terraform aws provider.

Comment: Since you are using very old TF version, have you tried with current versions? Maybe it was issue that  got already solved?

Comment: The behaviour is same in latest version of TF ( 0.14.10 ). I was able to workaround this issue by providing all the default values in Container Definitions, which was causing the recycling of task def. However, I still believe that this is a bug on Terraform or aws-provider.

Comment: You can open an [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues) for that.

Comment: This sort of effect can happen if the remote API doesn't store the original JSON as you submitted it but instead stores some data derived from it, and then reconstructs a new JSON representation when you read the data back. Without some special handling in the provider, it'll appear to Terraform like [drift](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/how-can-i-prevent-configuration-drift) and so the provider will plan to update or replace the object to "fix" it. Providers can potentially avoid this by adding extra rules to detect when two different values are functionally equivalent.

Comment: If this is an example of that situation then indeed it may be solvable by writing a normalization rule in the AWS provider, so it'll decide the equality of these values based on their effect rather than their raw JSON serialization.

Comment: @Marcin I have found existing GH issue in Terraform AWS Provider that talks about this.https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11526

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known [terraform aws provider bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11526)  for this issue.

In order to make terraform not replace the running task / container definition, I have to fill out all the default values that its showing on terraform plan with either null or empty sets of configuration.

Once all the parameters are filled out, I ran the terafform plan/apply cycle again to ensure its not replacing the container definition like it was doing it before.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue when I have the `aws-for-fluent-bit` as a sidecar container. Adding `"user": "0"` in this container definition is the least thing that can prevent the task definition from being force recreated.

```
{
  "name": "log_router",
  "image": "public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest",
  "logConfiguration": null,
  "firelensConfiguration": {
    "type": "fluentbit",
    "options": {
      "enable-ecs-log-metadata": "true"
    }
  },
  "user": "0"
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, Using `latest` version of the fluent bit can have some implications [ like https://github.com/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit/issues/233 ], I would recommend using `stable` version which will give you more robustness specially production environment.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can ignore any changes in `container_definitions` and add  `local.image_tag` to `replace_triggered_by`:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "this_task" {
  family                = "this-service"
  container_definitions = local.container_definitions
...
  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [local.image_tag]
    ignore_changes       = [container_definitions]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if we can pass local variables to replace_triggered_by, but you can try.
More about `lifecycle` here https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#replace_triggered_by

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned on previous answers and comments, as of today task definitions often force replacements and show unreliable diffs.

However, I managed to avoid the issue like this `v1.3.7` with AWS provider `registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.13.1`

- Create a separate `resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "example"` and setting on the corresponding `aws_ecs_service` the configuration `task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.example.arn`
- Inside the `aws_ecs_task_definition`, using `jsonencode` instead of `templatefile`, or anything similar to `<<TASK_DEFINITION`.

However, **this relies on `latest` being always the right Docker image version** or whatever you set on code. Anything other than `latest` would require some parameter manipulation to work.

More on `jsonencode`: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode